# Oracle Cloud Infrastructure – get Compute Shapes Across Regions?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am researching Oracle Cloud Infrastructure (OCI) services and trying to find out in which regions Compute Shapes are available.

The OCI Documentation contains information about Compute Shapes and Regions separately from each other:
"Compute Shapes": https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/computeshapes.htm#regions
"Regions and Availability Domains": https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/General/Concepts/regions.htm#top

**QUESTION**
I would like to find a source with aggregated "Compute Shape — Regions" information, as in the examples bellow.
The data should be up-to-date and publicly available (do not require access permissions or OCI account registration). Preferably, it should be an API, but I would appreciate any other options.

```
Examples:
1. «VM.Standard.E4» – Supported regions: Australia East (Sydney), Australia Southeast (Melbourne), Brazil East (Sao Paulo) …
2. «BM.Standard.A1» – Supported regions: Japan Central (Osaka), Japan East (Tokyo), South Korea Central (Seoul) …
3. …
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this document [Supported Regions](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/References/computeshapes.htm#regions) and check the supported regions for each compute shape in OCI.

Even you can check this document [For a list of compute instance service limits for the shape series:](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/General/Concepts/servicelimits.htm#Compute_Instances) and check Limits apply to each availability domain for compute shapes respectively with subscription type.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. But, it was the first thing which I started my research.
The information presented at Supported Regions cover just a part of Compute Shapes across regions. For example, it’s not clear at what regions GPU shapes or Previous Generation Shapes are available.
The page with Compute Instances limits, also contains just a part of Compute Instances. Some of them have limits for regions. For example, «VM.Standard.E4» and «BM.Standard.E4» limited by 6 cores for 23 mentioned regions. But, it’s not clear are these Compute Shapes unlimited in other regions? Or not available at all?

Answer (score 0):

oci-sdk provides "ComputeClient" (in which we can configure region for our api) you can iterate through all Regions, and notice like which all region have those shapes availability. Also these are IAAS api's. but you will get shapes based on your accountType- freeTier or PAYG.